# Imagens Sobrepostas e responsivas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bom dia,
         Amigos sou iniciante em CSS e estou usando o bootstrap e gostaria de colocar duas imagens sobrepostas, sendo que elas devem ser responsivas e a imagem2 tem que ter posição absoluta em relação a imagem1. Tem como?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow! Pedimos, por gentileza, que [leia este artigo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e edite sua pergunta para se enquadrar ao site! Muito Obrigado! Abraços!

Answer (score 1):

Seria isso?

```css
img{
  max-width: 100%;
}

.figure, img{
  position: relative;
}

.figure{
  max-width: 842px;
}

.figure img:last-child{
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 30%;
  margin-left: 35%;
  top: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<figure class="figure">
  <img src="http://msalx.viajeaqui.abril.com.br/2013/07/11/1112/6IivB/kuken-tepuy-timsnell-creative-commons.jpeg?1373556397" alt="" />  
  <img src="http://msalx.viajeaqui.abril.com.br/2013/07/11/1112/6IivB/kuken-tepuy-timsnell-creative-commons.jpeg?1373556397" alt="" />
</figure>
```

Só se atentar ao tamanho da imagem, no meu exemplo estou utilizando a mesma imagem, ou seja as duas tem o mesmo tamanho, caso tenha tamanho diferentes você terá que ajustar de acordo com a necessidade

Comment: Valdemiro, em adição a resposta do Lennon, acrescente a classe 'img-responsive' com o uso do bootstrap sua imagem automaticamente se tornará "responsiva".

Answer (score 0):

Para tornar as imagens responsivas você pode usar a classe [img-responsive](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_css_images.asp). Para deixar uma imagem sobre a outra, é possível com [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp), e deixar a posição absoluta na segunda imagem referente a uma `div` que comporte as duas. As classes das imagens podem ser:

```
#img1{
  z-index: 0;
}

#img2{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left:80px; 
  top: 80px;
}
```

**JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28065/

Comment: Talvez seria necessário `position: relative` na #img1?

Comment: Talvez sim @GabrielRanéaBarbosa, se ela estiver dentro de outro componente e com tamanho relativo também.